# D3 Tree layout: How to fill rectangles with text, but have them in uniform size?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am referencing this example to make my collapsible tree:

http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4339083

Currently my main goal is replacing the circles with rectangles and then filling the rectangles with my desired text.

After doing some research, I realize I was supposed to use [getBBox](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1160929) so that the dimensions of the rectangle will match that of the text. However, I believe the text I put in each rectangle may vary in length and thus will make each rectangle in the tree different sizes... ideally I would like to make each rectangle the same size so the tree looks consistent. Is there a way to achieve this? Thanks!

Relevant code:

```
  var node = svg.selectAll("g.node")
             .data(nodes, function(d) { return d.id || (d.id = ++i); });

  // Enter any new nodes at the parent's previous position.
  var nodeEnter = node.enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + source.x0 + "," + source.y0 + ")"; })
      .on("click", click);

  //where text is being appended... will need to use getBBox when appending rect
  var text = nodeEnter.append("text")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? -10 : 10; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.children || d._children ? "end" : "start"; })
      .text(function(d) { return d.name; });

  //var bbox = text.node().getBBox();

  nodeEnter.append("rect")
      .attr("width", rectW)
      .attr("height", rectH)
      .attr("stroke", "black")
      .attr("stroke-width", 1)
      .style("fill", function(d) { return d._children ? "lightsteelblue" : "#FFF"; });
```

All code is available on the website but if more information is needed, I'd be willing to provide it. The `datatest.json` is just something I made for those interested:

```
    {
    "name": "Group 1",
    "children": [
        {
            "name": "Sub Group 1",
                "children": [
                    {
                        "name": "A"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "B"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "C"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "D"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "E"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "F"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "G"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "H"
                    }
                ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Sub Group 2",
                    "children": [
                        {
                            "name": "I"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "J"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "K"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "L"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "M"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "N"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "O"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "P"
                        },
                        {
                            "name": "Q"
                        }
                    ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Person 1"
        },
        {
            "name": "Person 2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can compute the maximum bounding box text width just before inserting the rectangles:

```
// Insert the text elements ...

// Compute the maximum bounding box width
var maxTextWidth = d3.max(text, function() {
  return d3.select(this).node().getBBox();
});

// Insert the rect before the text element
nodeEnter.insert('rect', 'text')
 .attr("width", maxTextWidth)
 .attr("height", rectH);
```

Also, this way the text will be over the rectangles.

Comment: So what I realized was that because my tree does not display all the information from the text file, it will get the longest word and set the maxWidth to that but if we were to expand and find a longer word, it would not be able to redraw old rectangles. I think I'm going to change my strategy and simply use fixed rectangles but thanks for the answer.

Comment: You can update the rectangles later also, you can select the text elements on expand, compute the new max width and set the attribute for all the rectangles.

Comment: but wouldn't that make it show up to the users that the rectangles are constantly changing sizes whenever they expand/collapse children? I think that's something I'm trying to avoid haha but I might try playing around with that idea :)

Comment: Should this be getBBox().width; instead of just getBBox(), since it's computing the max *width* and getBBox() doesn't return a scalar?

Comment: I also couldn't get my own (similar) code working using d3.select(this).node().getBBox(). That failed with Object [object Array] has no method 'getBBox'. Changing the call to d3.max(text[0], function(el) {
  return (el).getBBox().width;
}) is what worked for me...